# Read xml data into a SQL table

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to read the xml string and push the data into a SQL table. I have this data in a SQL variable

```
<Policy>
   <No>
       <old>1</old>
       <new>2</new>
   </No>
   <name>
       <old>xxx</old>
       <new>yyy</new>
   </name>
   <amount>
       <old>1000</old>
       <new>1500</new>
   </amount>
</Policy>
<Policy>
    <No>
        <old>3</old>
        <new>4</new>
    </No>
    <name>
        <old>aaa</old>
        <new>bbb</new>
    </name>
    <amount>
        <old>2000</old>
        <new>2500</new>
    </amount>
</Policy>
<Policy>
    <No>
        <old>5</old>
        <new>6</new>
    </No>
    <name>
        <old>qqq</old>
        <new>www</new>
    </name>
    <amount>
        <old>1000</old>
        <new>1500</new>
    </amount>
</Policy>
```

I want to interpret the data as old & new

like

OLD

```
No   Name amount
-----------------    
1    xxx  1000
3    aaa  2000
5    qqq  1000
```

New

```
No   Name amount
----------------
2    yyy  1500
4    bbb  2500
6    www  1500
```

Thanks,

Kihtrak J

Comment: If you want to we help you, You need to be more specific e.g. What typ of SQL and whic version are you using, How you want to accompish this by mking app or using sql by itself, From where there XML comming, resident in table or from client. Who is going to make translation Clinet or server, what have you tierd so far etc

Comment: **SQL** is just a query language - you don't have *tables* in **SQL** - you tables in a **DATABASE** that uses SQL - but you're not telling us **WHAT** database you're using. Please add relevent tags (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL) to your question!

Comment: Im trying to read the data from the xml variabel in SQL server 2008 R2. SELECT * FROM @xml.nodes('/Policy') Tab(Col)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have this XML in a SQL Server variable called `@XmlData`, you can use these native XQuery expressions to get what you're looking for:

```
-- select "old" data
SELECT
    OldNo = XC.value('(No/old)[1]', 'int'),
    OldName = XC.value('(name/old)[1]', 'varchar(25)'),
    OldAmount = XC.value('(amount/old)[1]', 'decimal(20,2)')
FROM 
    @XmlData.nodes('/Policy') AS XT(XC)

-- select "new" data
SELECT
    NewNo = XC.value('(No/new)[1]', 'int'),
    NewName = XC.value('(name/new)[1]', 'varchar(25)'),
    NewAmount = XC.value('(amount/new)[1]', 'decimal(20,2)')
FROM 
    @XmlData.nodes('/Policy') AS XT(XC)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have only 1 root (top-level) element in your XML document.

Then... try doing something like this.

```
DECLARE @DocHandle int
DECLARE @XmlDocument nvarchar(max)
SET @XmlDocument = N'<ROOT><Policy>
   <No>
       <old>1</old>
       <new>2</new>
   </No>
   <name>
       <old>xxx</old>
       <new>yyy</new>
   </name>
   <amount>
       <old>1000</old>
       <new>1500</new>
   </amount>
</Policy>
<Policy>
    <No>
        <old>3</old>
        <new>4</new>
    </No>
    <name>
        <old>aaa</old>
        <new>bbb</new>
    </name>
    <amount>
        <old>2000</old>
        <new>2500</new>
    </amount>
</Policy>
<Policy>
    <No>
        <old>5</old>
        <new>6</new>
    </No>
    <name>
        <old>qqq</old>
        <new>www</new>
    </name>
    <amount>
        <old>1000</old>
        <new>1500</new>
    </amount>
</Policy></ROOT>'


-- Create an internal representation of the XML document.
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument

-- Execute a SELECT statement using OPENXML rowset provider.
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/ROOT/Policy/No', 2)
      WITH 
    (
        no_old varchar(200) 'old',
        no_new varchar(200) 'new',
        name_old varchar(200) '../name/old',
        name_new varchar(200) '../name/new',
        amount_old varchar(200) '../amount/old',
        amount_new varchar(200) '../amount/new'
    )

--- Clean up the internal representation.
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle
```

For more details check out these two MSDN pages:

[OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[OPENXML examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187897%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)